# Laravel Images in Public Folder

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am trying to integrate innovastudios contentbuilder.js (http://innovastudio.com/content-builder.aspx) in my existing laravel 5 project and facing some issues.
The JS is working properly, but I am missing some pictures from my public folder.

my site structure is:

edit.blade.php inside here I am loading the contentbuilder.js especially a snippets file (snippet.blde.php). This contains all elements that I want to drag&drop

The snippets.blade.php file is located inside: public/backend/contentBuilder/assets/

The code to load the snippets.blade.php is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
          $("#contentarea").contentbuilder({
              //snippetFile: 'assets/minimalist-basic/snippets.html',
                        snippetFile: "{{asset('backend/contentBuilder/assets/simple/snippets.blade.php')}}",
              snippetOpen: true,
              toolbar: 'left',
              iconselect: 'assets/ionicons/selecticon.html'
          });
      });
```

In my snippets.blade.php I have referenced all images with {{asset('')}}
This is my snippets.blade.php:

```
    <div data-thumb="{{asset('backend/contentBuilder/assets/simple/thumbnails/theme1_thumb.png')}}">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row" style="height: 900px; width: 635px; overflow: hidden; margin: auto;">
            <img class="img-noscale" src='{{asset('backend/contentBuilder/assets/simple/images/6.jpg')}}' style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: relative;" />
          </div>      
      </div>
    </div>
```

What I get in my view is an error with:
"http://localhost:8000/backend/flyers/10/%7B%7Basset('backend/contentBuilder/assets/simple/thumbnails/theme1_thumb.png')%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)"

It looks like {{assets('...')}} is not pointing to my public folder!
Any idea why?

Comment: Is the js code snippet you mentioned above present in snippets.blade.php?

Comment: Try running `php artisan laroute:generate` - if you are using laravel's in build JS route helpers, you occasionally need to regenerate it whenever you move paths about.

Comment: @carl:                                                                   
 
  Command "route:generate" is not defined.                        
  Did you mean one of these?                                      
      event:generate                                              
      key:generate                                                
      route:list                                                  
      route:clear                                                 
      route:cache

Comment: @GokulSrinivas: No snippets doesn't contain JS. Just HTML Markup. I've updated my initial post, with the content of snippet.blade.php

Comment: @Mamulasa: Quick question. The Javascript is not in any blade.php file. which means that it will not be processed by the blade templating engine. Then how will the {{asset('your/path/')}} be replaced by the actual path?

Comment: @ GokulSrinivas: Right. The JS is inside edit.blade.php. I am pulling snippets.blade.php inside with the contentbuilder() . I thought I can point to my public folder with {{asset(' ... ')}} inside the snippets.blade.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the JS code snippet that you have provided.

Instead of defining the snippetFile with the `asset()` helper,

In your `file.blade.php` add this snippet at the beginning inside the `<head>` tag.

So, your blade looks like this

```
<head>
<script> var base_url = "{{asset('/')}}"; </script>
...
... your script file included here
</head>
```

And in your JS code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
          $("#contentarea").contentbuilder({
              //snippetFile: 'assets/minimalist-basic/snippets.html',
                        snippetFile: base_url + "backend/contentBuilder/assets/simple/snippets.blade.php",
              snippetOpen: true,
              toolbar: 'left',
              iconselect: 'assets/ionicons/selecticon.html'
          });
      });
```

Also, I think there might be another small problem.

The `blade.php` is not processed if it is not returned via the `view()` through a controller.

So, add a method in your controller that processes the blade like so

```
function returnThumbnail(Request $request) {
return view('snippet');
}
```

Make sure the `snippet.blade.php` is in the `resources/views` folder.

Then add a route like so

```
Route::get('/path/to/snippet', 'YourController@returnThumbnail');
```

And, in your Javascript,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
          $("#contentarea").contentbuilder(
              snippetFile: base_url + "path/to/snippet",
              snippetOpen: true,
              toolbar: 'left',
              iconselect: 'assets/ionicons/selecticon.html'
          });
```

Comment: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8000/come/base_url".  ?Error mesage and not know why? when I use in the css <link rel="stylesheet" href=base_url +"js/bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> PS:the js is in public/js/....